# Referencing a match statement when populating an array

Tags: arrays, scala

I have been set a simple task to create a TicTacToe game, using arrays.
I have a class 'Player' with the objects 'X' and 'O'

I have the following Match statement:

```
def optPlayerToChar(p: Option[Player]): Char = p match {
  case None    => ' '
  case Some(O) => 'O'
  case Some(X) => 'X'
}
```

I have the following declaration for the grid:

```
private var grid: Array[Array[Option[Player]]] = ofDim[Option[Player]](3,3)
```

I need to be able to populate the grid at (x)(y) using the match statement. I have tried many things but can't seem to get it to work for some reason. Apologies if it is just a simple solution I am overlooking.

it needs to be in a format like the following but obviously functioning:

```
grid(x)(y) = optPlayerToChar(p: Option[Player])
```

---

the code I am using to show the grid (in case you need it):

```
def showGrid() {
  println()
  for(j <- 0 to 2) {
      print("  "  + optPlayerToChar(grid(0)(j)))
      print(" | " + optPlayerToChar(grid(1)(j)))
      print(" | " + optPlayerToChar(grid(2)(j)))
      println()
      if (j<2) println(" --- --- --- ")
  }
  println()
}
```

Comment: So, what's the actual problem?

Answer (score 2):

You define your `grid` but you don't populate it, so it is populated with `null` by default. `null` isn't the same thing as `None`.

```
val grid: Array[Array[Option[Player]]] = 
  Array.fill[Option[Player]](3,3)(None)
```

With this, `optPlayerToChar()` and `showGrid()` should work as planned.

This won't work `grid(x)(y) = optPlayerToChar(p: Option[Player])` because each `grid` element is an `Option[Player]` but `optPlayerToChar()` returns a `Char`. Those are, of course, unrelated and incompatible types.

Note: There's no reason to make `grid` a `var`. Arrays are mutable. The variable usually doesn't need to be mutable as well.